# CheckConsecutiveElements in a list

Tags: java

I have a problem with an algoritm (JAVA) that check consecutive elements in a list.

For example:
list: [1,2,3,3,4,5,3,3] ==> I want: how many times number 3 is consecutive twice? Result: 2

This is my code but i haven't a good result...

public class CheckConsecutiveElements {

```
/**
 * Returns the number of groups containing "numOfOccs" occurrences of element "elem" passed as argument.
 *
 * @param  numOfOccs     the exact number of consecutive occurrences
 * @param  elem            the element to search occurrences for
 * @param  whereToFind   the array to search for repetitions
 * @return number of groups with "numOfOccs" consecutive repetitions of element "elem"
 */

public int nGroup(int numOfOccs,int elem, int[] whereToFind) {
    int contador=0;
    if (numOfOccs==0 || whereToFind==null) //case null
        return contador;
    for (int i=0; i<whereToFind.length; i++){
        if(whereToFind[i]!=elem)  //if "elem" doesn't appear on the array
            return contador;
        for (int j=1; j<whereToFind.length; j++){
            if(whereToFind[i]==elem && (whereToFind[i]==whereToFind[j]))
                contador++;
        }

    }

    return contador;
}
```

}

I have this output now on console:

```
*** Error: check_consecutive_elements returns 6 groups
instead of 2 when counting groups of 2 repetitions of element 4 in the array
 [4,4,4]
```

Examples:

nGroup(0, 2, {1,2,2,2,3,2}) ==> 0

nGroup(1, 2, {1,2,2,2,3,2}) ==> 4

nGroup(2, 2, {1,2,2,2,3,2}) ==> 2

nGroup(3, 2, {1,2,2,2,3,2}) ==> 1

nGroup(4, 2, {1,2,2,2,3,2}) ==> 0

Can you help me? thanks...

Comment: What is the expected output for `nGroup(2,2,{1,2,2,2,2,3,2})` ? In short, how do you treat a value repeated m > numOfOccs times ?

Comment: The expected output for that is: 3 , because you can take 3 groups of 2 numbers 2. for see better nGroup(NumberOfConsecutiveRepetitions, NumberToSearch, [Array])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that will do what you ask:

```
private static int nGroup(final int numOfOccs, final int elem, final int[] whereToFind) {
    if(numOfOccs == 0 || whereToFind == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int res = 0;
    int streakLength = 0;
    for (final int i : whereToFind) {
        if (elem != i) {
            streakLength = 0;
        } else if (++streakLength >= numOfOccs) {
            res++;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

I'd have given some pseudo-code and some explanation instead but I believe that the algorithm is simple enough to be understood by anyone. If not, please just let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly ;)

---

Running against your test case:

```
System.out.println(nGroup(0, 2, new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2 }));
System.out.println(nGroup(1, 2, new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2 }));
System.out.println(nGroup(2, 2, new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2 }));
System.out.println(nGroup(3, 2, new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2 }));
System.out.println(nGroup(4, 2, new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2 }));
```

... will produce the following output:

```
0
4
2
1
0
```

Comment: Thanks, my fail was that I don't consider anything with numOfOccs as i see on your code.

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped you out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done, along with some tests :

```
 public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println(nGroup(0,2,new int[]{1,2,2,2,3,2}));   //0
        System.out.println(nGroup(1,2,new int[]{1,2,2,2,3,2}));   //4
        System.out.println(nGroup(2,2,new int[]{1,2,2,2,3,2}));   //2
        System.out.println(nGroup(3,2,new int[]{1,2,2,2,3,2}));   //1
        System.out.println(nGroup(4,2,new int[]{1,2,2,2,3,2}));   //0
        System.out.println(nGroup(2,2,new int[]{1,2,2,2,2,3,2})); //3
    }

    public static int nGroup(int nOccs, int val, int[] arr) {
        int count = 0;
        if (nOccs == 0 || arr == null)
            return count;

        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            int occs;
            for (occs = 0 ; i<arr.length && arr[i] == val ; i++, occs++);
            if (occs >= nOccs) count += occs - nOccs + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: I think that this is slightly over-complicated: you could simply have a **single** for-loop and increment `count` by `1` every time you are encountering an element that is equals to `elem` (and the streak we're on is at least of `numOfOccs` elements). My answer features a (IMO) simpler approach, if you'd like to have a look at it ;)

Comment: @ccjmne : this is not that complicated, it is just a different way to do it and has the same time complexity.